# Volume of Rotation

Tags: calculus, volume, rotations, solid-of-revolution

Let $W_n$ be the region in an $xy$-plane that’s bounded by the $y$-axis and the parabola $x=y^2-n^2$.

Find the value of $n$ for which the volume obtained by rotating $W_n$ about the $y$-axis is precisely 16 times the volume obtained by rotating $W_n$ about the $x$-axis.

Comment: I'm kind of confused on how to start. So far I know that once I find volume about y-axis & the volume about x-axis, I set them equal and solve for n

Comment: @AmR Sounds good so far,  How would you find the volume of revolution around the y axis and the volume of revolution around the x axis?

Comment: Make a start. Do you know how to write the integral to calculate volume about x-axis?

Comment: For the x-axis I got π∫(y^2-n^2)^2 dx  I'm sorry about the formatting, my computer is really slow/old

Comment: That's not necessary. I see that the difference in what we both did is that I considered rotation of the curve in a single quadrant and you considered the curve in two quadrants (negative $x$). It's unusual to specify a solid of revolution about an axis within the area being revolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets start with the y-axis revolution.

We are integrating from $-n$ to $n$.

We get $2π\displaystyle \int_0^{n}(n^2-y^2)^2\,dy = \frac{16}{15}πn^5$

I put a $2$ in front for symmetry and ease in calculation.

Next, we do x-axis revolution. This one is a little bit tricky, we have to rewrite in terms of $x$.

$x=y^2-n^2$ turns into $y=\sqrt{x+n^2}$

No plus or minus because either one would produce the needed solid. Using shells would cover the volume of the solid TWICE.

We get $π\displaystyle \int_{-n^2}^{0}(x+n^2)\,dx = \frac{1}{2}πn^4$.

So we get $\displaystyle \frac{16}{15}πn^5=16 \times \frac{1}{2}πn^4$.

That means $\frac{16}{15}πn^5=8πn^4$.

We get $\frac{16}{15}n=8$.

Therefore, $\boxed{n=\displaystyle \frac{15}{2}}$.

Comment: Could you please clarify why the 2 is necessary in the front in the third line?

Comment: @AmR The two is not necessary. Instead of integrating from -n to n, we can simply integrate from 0 to n. the solid is symmetrical to the plane y=0. doing so simplifies the calculations when done by hand

Comment: So the 2 shows that it's symmetric? I'm still confused because the person who answered below said n=15, meaning they didn't use the 2, so I was wondering why.

Comment: No, they did not need the 2, and I didn't need the 2 either. The difference between our answers is actually the x integral.

Comment: Think about it this way: a semicircle revolved around the x axis is a sphere. what about a full circle?

Comment: A full circle would be twice that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60038/discussion-between-amr-and-saketh-malyala).

Comment: When you consider that $y\in[-n,n]$ you are not rotating the same area as when you take $x\in[-n^2,0]$. In fact, it's twice the area, and that why our results differ by a factor of 2. As I said in my solution, my results are verified numerically.

Comment: Yes, that is true. Indeed, they are different volumes. However, if you rotate from y = -n to y=n, you will end up with twice the volume.

Comment: Have you checked wolfram alpha?

Comment: Wrote my own program that does the complete integration of the area, centroid and , volumes in the complex plane. It's fool proof and I've been using it for years. Have you plotted the function?

Comment: try not using centroids, and using regular disks? do you get the same answer? and yes i did

Comment: You're not listening to me. You're using the wrong curve to rotate about the x-axis.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60042/discussion-between-saketh-malyala-and-cye-waldman).

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that I can write $x=n^2-y^2$ and that the ranges of the variables are then given by $x\in[0,n^2],\,\,y\in[0,n]$. Now I'll invoke Pappus's $(2^{nd})$ Centroid Theorem: the volume of a planar area of revolution is the product of the area $A$ and the length of the path traced by its centroid $R$, i.e., $2πR$. The volume is simply $V=2πRA$. Finally, I'll express $RA$ in the complex plane so that I can't compute it for the both the $x$ and $y$ components at the same time. Thus.

$$
\begin{align}
RA
&=\int_0^n\int_0^{n^2-y^2}(x+iy)dx\,dy\\
&=\int_0^n\left(\frac{x^2}{2}+ixy\right)\big|_0^{n^2-y^2}\,dy\\
&=\int_0^n\left(\frac{(n^2-y^2)^2}{2}+i(n^2-y^2)y\right)dy\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\left[n^5-\frac{2n^5}{3}+\frac{n^5}{5}\right]+i\left[\frac{n^4}{2}-\frac{n^4}{4}\right]
\end{align}
$$

Then setting

$$\frac{\Re\{RA\}}{\Im\{RA\}}=16=\frac{\frac{n}{2}\frac{8}{15}}{\frac{1}{4}}\Rightarrow n=15$$

I have verified this result numerically.